# How to create a nested JSON from a simple CSV via Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, pandas

I am looking for a way to create a nested JSON from a simple CSV via Python. I am this far that I am capable to create a Json from the CSV and it looks like it is supposed to. But I would like to put some attributes from the CSV in one JSON Array because they belong together.

Input CSV:

`Ansprechpartner, Telefon, Fax, eMail
 Elin Persson,+46 (0)243 224360,+46 (0) 243 81322,info@borlangect.se`

Output JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Ansprechpartner": ["Elin Persson","+46 (0)243 224360","+46 (0) 243 81322","info@borlangect.se"]
  }
]
```

My already existing output:

```
[
  {
    "Fax": "+46 (0) 243 81322", 
    "eMail": "info@borlangect.se", 
    "Telefon": "+46 (0)243 224360", 
    "Ansprechpartner": "Elin Persson"
  }
]
```

Python Code:

```
import csv
import json


#open CSV / read / create list
with open('Ansprechpartner.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)      
    rows = list(reader)

#open JSON / input list 
with open('test.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(rows,f,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Could please someone help me to create this array in the JSOn file?
Thank you

Comment: Can there be more than one person? What would the CSV look like in that case?

Comment: No, there can't be more than one person.

Answer (score 0):

DictReader maps the information a dict,you should use [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) method.

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called —
>   file objects and list objects are both suitable.

And then just convert it into list you can easily operate it.

```
import csv
import json

rows = []

with open('a.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = list(reader)
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        rows.append({lines[i][0]: lines[i + 1]})

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And you will get:

```
[
  {
    "Ansprechpartner": [
      "Elin Persson", 
      "+46 (0)243 224360", 
      "+46 (0) 243 81322", 
      "info@borlangect.se"
    ]
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.